# Python 2.7 using twill, saving downloaded file properly

Tags: python, twill

```
import twill
twill.commands.agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120910144328 Firefox/15.0.2")
twill.commands.go('loginpage...')

twill.commands.fv("1", "txtUserName", "username")
twill.commands.fv("1", "txtPassword", "password")

# Login Page
twill.commands.submit()

# Pre Registration Report Selection
twill.commands.submit()

# Generate and download the report.
twill.commands.go("ReportGenerator.ashx")

print "Done!"

twill.commands.redirect_output('PreRegistration.xls')
#twill.commands.save_html('PreRegistration.xls')
```

That is what i'm attempting to use currently.

The website works as such:

1. Login page redirects to another form that lets me choose the report to generate.
2. I want all default choices so i just submit the page again.
3. I then visit another page which generates the report and then force downloads the file.

redirect_output does not save the xls file.

save_html does save the information BUT it corrupts something and Excel is unable to read it at all. I use kdiff to checkout any differences, it claims there are lots but the data on left/right is identical, wondering if it's an issue with line-endings..etc. Not 100% sure.

I have checked the commands page on twill's website, but i'm unsure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i suspected it was a line-ending issue. Modified twill's save_html function to write as 'wb' instead of 'w', all is well.

Comment: Alternative way getting binary content with `requests` using `twill` cookie jar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910736/python-twill-download-file-accessible-through-php-script/37911758#37911758